# Why won't this code work in python but when I telnet It does?

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, telnet, telnetlib

What I am trying to do it make a GUI to control a raspberry pi bot. I have telnet to wirelessly connect to it. When I telnet to it from a terminal on my computer, I can run `echo 1=230 > /dev/servoblaster` to make one of the servos move.

However, when using that same piece of code in the python GUI, it does not make the servo move, but I don't get an error message either. At one point it was all working but then suddenly it stopped.

Below is a simplified version of the python script that I am using for my GUI:

```
from tkinter import *
import telnetlib

bot = telnetlib.Telnet("192.168.1.128")
bot.read_until(b"login: ")
bot.write(("pi \n").encode('ascii'))
bot.read_until(b"Password: ")
bot.write(("pi \n").encode('ascii'))
bot.write(("cd /home/pi/pibits/ServoBlaster/user \n").encode('ascii'))
bot.write(("sudo ./servod \n").encode('ascii'))
bot.write(("cd \n").encode('ascii'))

bot.write(("echo 1=230 > /dev/servoblaster \n").encode('ascii'))
```

Would someone be able to help me work out why when I connect to the bot from a terminal I can control it but when running the same command with the above code nothing happens, not even an error message.

Just in case this is of any use, I know the above code is at least reaching the wireless receiver of my raspberry pi because the lights on it flash every time it receives a signal.

Thanks

Comment: Btw, you can omit parentheses around string literals — `'something'.encode('ascii')` would work just fine.

Comment: I doubt you wants spaces before `\n` in any of those lines, especially not the login and password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your space in the username and password commands are keeping your telnet session from actually logging into the pi bot. The spaces aren't ignored.

You need:

```
bot.read_until(b"login: ")
bot.write("pi\n".encode('ascii'))
bot.read_until(b"Password: ")
bot.write("pi\n".encode('ascii'))
```

Comment: If this was an actual issue, how did it previously work? "At one point it was all working but then suddenly it stopped.", according to OP.

Comment: It is an actual issue because sending spaces in username / password using telnetlib causes login failure. You can verify it on your own using a Linux box.

Comment: Yep, no doubts this was an issue. I'm just curious how did it work previously. It couldn't.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org) to figure out what is actually is being sent by your client and what does your Raspberry Pi respond.

I strongly suspect the cause of your problem is that you are waiting for wrong pattern — e.g. it may be `b'Login: '`, or `b'login:'`, or anything else, and that may change with updating your `getty` or similar binary, and Wireshark will help you localize your problem.

To see only telnet traffic with your Pi box, use following capture filter:

```
host 192.168.1.128 and port 23
```

Comment: "login: " with lowercase is standard for telnetd so his code looks ok there. The problem is what he is sending. FYI I did not downvote because the wireshark suggestion is still good.